# Angular JS Table Formatting

Tags: angularjs

I have a AngularJS application in which I have a table as You can see in the image below,

[image]

as you can see the last column contains a delete and and a edit button for every row. How can I highlight row when the corresponding delete button is pressed?

Here is my code: https://plnkr.co/edit/ZNzgVO59eWJSVMH7?preview

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.constant('Employees',

    [{ Name: "Ishan", Code: 1, Is_Intern: "Yes", DateOfJoining: "01/02/2022", Skills: "VB, DOT.NET, Angular", Status: "Working" },
    { Name: "Ashwin", Code: 2, Is_Intern: "No", DateOfJoining: "21/03/2021", Skills: "VB, Ruby, Angular", Status: "Inactive" },
    { Name: "Shailesh", Code: 3, Is_Intern: "Yes", DateOfJoining: "27/04/2021", Skills: "VB, Python, Angular", Status: "Working" },
    { Name: "Pawan", Code: 4, Is_Intern: "No", DateOfJoining: "14/01/2022", Skills: "VB, Sapphire, Angular", Status: "Inactive" }]);

myApp.component('employeeDetail', {

    bindings: {
        Name: '<',
        Code: '<',
        Is_Intern: '<',
        DateOfJoining: '<',
        Skills: '<',
    },

    controller: 'empCtrl',
});

myApp.controller('empCtrl', function empCtrl($scope, Employees) {

    $scope.EmployeeDetails = Employees;

    $scope.Name = Employees.Name;
    $scope.Code = Employees.Code;
    $scope.Is_Intern = Employees.Is_Intern;
    $scope.DateOfJoining = Employees.DateOfJoining;
    $scope.Skills = Employees.Skills;
    $scope.Status = Employees.Status;


    $scope.add = function () {

        $scope.EmployeeDetails.push({

            Name: $scope.Name,
            Code: $scope.Code,
            Is_Intern: $scope.Is_Intern,
            DateOfJoining: $scope.DateOfJoining,
            Skills: $scope.Skills,
            Status: $scope.Status,
        });
        $scope.id = '';
        $scope.Code = '';
        $scope.Is_Intern = '';
        $scope.DateOfJoining = '';
        $scope.Skills = '';
        $scope.Status = '';
    };

    function select(Name) {

        for (let i = 0; i < $scope.EmployeeDetails.length; i++) {
            if ($scope.EmployeeDetails[i].Name == Name) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    };

    $scope.edit = function (Name) {

        let index = select(Name);
        let emp = $scope.EmployeeDetails[index];
        $scope.Name = emp.Name;
        $scope.Code = emp.Code;
        $scope.Is_Intern = emp.Is_Intern;
        $scope.DateOfJoining = emp.DateOfJoining;
        $scope.Skills = emp.Skills;
        $scope.Status = emp.Status;
    }

    $scope.save = function () {

        let index = select($scope.Name);
        $scope.EmployeeDetails[index].Name = $scope.Name;
        $scope.EmployeeDetails[index].Code = $scope.Code;
        $scope.EmployeeDetails[index].Is_Intern = $scope.Is_Intern;
        $scope.EmployeeDetails[index].DateOfJoining = $scope.DateOfJoining;
        $scope.EmployeeDetails[index].Skills = $scope.Skills;
        $scope.EmployeeDetails[index].Status = $scope.Status;

        $scope.Name = '';
        $scope.Code = '';
        $scope.Is_Intern = '';
        $scope.DateOfJoining = '';
        $scope.Skills = '';
        $scope.Status = '';
    }

    $scope.delete = function (emp) {
        if (confirm("Are You Sure You want to delete this record ?")) {
            $scope.EmployeeDetails.splice(emp, 1)
            alert("Deleted")
        }
    }

    $scope.selectedRow = null;
    $scope.setClickedRow = function (index) {
        $scope.selectedRow = index;
    }
});
```

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    font-family: Arial;
}

td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
}

th {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}

label,
input {
    display: block;
}

label {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.8.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="empCtrl">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <th colspan="8">Names of Employees</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Code</th>
                <th>Is_Intern</th>
                <th>Skills</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>DateOfJoining</th>
                <th colspan="2" style="text-align: center;">Action</th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="emp in EmployeeDetails">
                <td>{{emp.Name}}</td>
                <td>{{emp.Code}}</td>
                <td>{{emp.Is_Intern}}</td>
                <td>{{emp.Skills}}</td>
                <td>{{emp.Status}}</td>
                <td>{{emp.DateOfJoining}}</td>
                <td><button ng-click="edit(emp.Name)">Edit</button></td>
                <td><button ng-click="delete($index)">Delete</button></td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
        <label>
            Name
            <input ng-model="Name" type="text" />
        </label>
        <label>
            Code
            <input ng-model="Code" type="number" />
        </label>
        <label>
            Is_Intern
            <input ng-model="Is_Intern" type="text" />
        </label>
        <label>
            Skills
            <input ng-model="Skills" type="text" />
        </label>
        <label>
            Status
            <input ng-model="Status" type="text" />
        </label>
        <label>
            Date Of Joining
            <input ng-model="DateOfJoining" type="text" />
        </label>
        <label>
            <button ng-click="add()">Add</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        </label>
        <button ng-click="save()">Update</button><br><br>
    </table>
    <br>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved by using `ng-class` in angular js.

**Logic.**

- On delete button click set some flag on the row to indicate that the row is active I used an `isActive` class.
- Then use a `ng-class` condition, `ng-class="{'highlight': emp.isActive == true}"`.
- Since you are making use of a JavaScript `confirm` method, you have to use a `setTimeout` function to trigger the `confirm` dialog. Or else the changes will not be visible in the DOM.
- Since you have used `setTimeout`, you have to use `$scope.$apply()` to get your changes reflected in the UI.

Working Fiddle.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.constant('Employees',

    [{ Name: "Ishan", Code: 1, Is_Intern: "Yes", DateOfJoining: "01/02/2022", Skills: "VB, DOT.NET, Angular", Status: "Working" },
    { Name: "Ashwin", Code: 2, Is_Intern: "No", DateOfJoining: "21/03/2021", Skills: "VB, Ruby, Angular", Status: "Inactive" },
    { Name: "Shailesh", Code: 3, Is_Intern: "Yes", DateOfJoining: "27/04/2021", Skills: "VB, Python, Angular", Status: "Working" },
    { Name: "Pawan", Code: 4, Is_Intern: "No", DateOfJoining: "14/01/2022", Skills: "VB, Sapphire, Angular", Status: "Inactive" }]);

myApp.component('employeeDetail', {

    bindings: {
        Name: '<',
        Code: '<',
        Is_Intern: '<',
        DateOfJoining: '<',
        Skills: '<',
    },

    controller: 'empCtrl',
});

myApp.controller('empCtrl', function empCtrl($scope, Employees) {

    $scope.EmployeeDetails = Employees;

    $scope.Name = Employees.Name;
    $scope.Code = Employees.Code;
    $scope.Is_Intern = Employees.Is_Intern;
    $scope.DateOfJoining = Employees.DateOfJoining;
    $scope.Skills = Employees.Skills;
    $scope.Status = Employees.Status;


    $scope.add = function () {

        $scope.EmployeeDetails.push({

            Name: $scope.Name,
            Code: $scope.Code,
            Is_Intern: $scope.Is_Intern,
            DateOfJoining: $scope.DateOfJoining,
            Skills: $scope.Skills,
            Status: $scope.Status,
        });
        $scope.id = '';
        $scope.Code = '';
        $scope.Is_Intern = '';
        $scope.DateOfJoining = '';
        $scope.Skills = '';
        $scope.Status = '';
    };

    function select(Name) {

        for (let i = 0; i < $scope.EmployeeDetails.length; i++) {
            if ($scope.EmployeeDetails[i].Name == Name) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    };

    $scope.edit = function (Name) {

        let index = select(Name);
        let emp = $scope.EmployeeDetails[index];
        $scope.Name = emp.Name;
        $scope.Code = emp.Code;
        $scope.Is_Intern = emp.Is_Intern;
        $scope.DateOfJoining = emp.DateOfJoining;
        $scope.Skills = emp.Skills;
        $scope.Status = emp.Status;
    }

    $scope.save = function () {

        let index = select($scope.Name);
        $scope.EmployeeDetails[index].Name = $scope.Name;
        $scope.EmployeeDetails[index].Code = $scope.Code;
        $scope.EmployeeDetails[index].Is_Intern = $scope.Is_Intern;
        $scope.EmployeeDetails[index].DateOfJoining = $scope.DateOfJoining;
        $scope.EmployeeDetails[index].Skills = $scope.Skills;
        $scope.EmployeeDetails[index].Status = $scope.Status;

        $scope.Name = '';
        $scope.Code = '';
        $scope.Is_Intern = '';
        $scope.DateOfJoining = '';
        $scope.Skills = '';
        $scope.Status = '';
    }

    $scope.deleteRow = function (emp, row) {
        row.isActive = true;
        setTimeout(function () {
            $scope.delete(emp, row);
        });
    }

    $scope.delete = function (emp, row) {
        if (confirm("Are You Sure You want to delete this record ?")) {
            $scope.EmployeeDetails.splice(emp, 1)
            $scope.$apply();
            alert("Deleted");
        }
        row.isActive = false;
    }

    $scope.selectedRow = null;
    $scope.setClickedRow = function (index) {
        $scope.selectedRow = index;
    }
});
```

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    font-family: Arial;
}

td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
}

th {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}

label,
input {
    display: block;
}

label {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.highlight {
    background: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.8.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="empCtrl">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <th colspan="8">Names of Employees</th>


        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Code</th>
                <th>Is_Intern</th>
                <th>Skills</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>DateOfJoining</th>
                <th colspan="2" style="text-align: center;">Action</th>

            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="emp in EmployeeDetails" ng-class="{'highlight': emp.isActive == true}">
                <td>{{emp.Name}} - {{ emp.isActive }}</td>
                <td>{{emp.Code}}</td>
                <td>{{emp.Is_Intern}}</td>
                <td>{{emp.Skills}}</td>
                <td>{{emp.Status}}</td>
                <td>{{emp.DateOfJoining}}</td>
                <td><button ng-click="edit(emp.Nam, emp)">Edit</button></td>
                <td><button ng-click="deleteRow($index, emp)">Delete</button></td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
        <label>
            Name
            <input ng-model="Name" type="text" />
        </label>
        <label>
            Code
            <input ng-model="Code" type="number" />
        </label>
        <label>
            Is_Intern
            <input ng-model="Is_Intern" type="text" />
        </label>
        <label>
            Skills
            <input ng-model="Skills" type="text" />
        </label>
        <label>
            Status
            <input ng-model="Status" type="text" />
        </label>
        <label>
            Date Of Joining
            <input ng-model="DateOfJoining" type="text" />
        </label>
        <label>
            <button ng-click="add()">Add</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        </label>
        <button ng-click="save()">Update</button><br><br>
    </table>
    <br>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank You So Much Your Answer Helped a Lot.